# How to show multiple results in a query result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I have to populate him with a query result. One of the rows is the name of the group. My result3 inside the while is a query where I get the name of the group. I want to put that name in each row. But for some reason I can only get the first position of the query result. Can you help me?
This is my result3 variable query(in a resumed way):

```
 $sql3 = "SELECT * from titulogrupo where idutilizador ={$_SESSION['id_utilizador']}";
 $result3 = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(", "u518178166_serra"), $sql3);...etc etc...



<table table id= "myTable" class="table table-hover"> <br>
                   <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Os meus Chips</th>
                      <th>NIF</th>
                      <th>Marca de Exploracao</th>
                      <th>Marca do Auricular</th>
                      <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
                      <th>Observacoes</th>
                      <th>Estado</th>
                      <th>Data1</th>
                      <th>Data2</th>
                      <th>Data3</th>


                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <?php
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row['numerochip'];?><input style="float: left; margin: 0 5px;" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['numerochip']; ?>" name="numero[]" id="numero"></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['NIF']; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['MarcaExploracao']; ?> </td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['MarcaAuricular']; ?> </td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['Data_Nascimento']; ?> </td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['observacoes'];?>

                      <div class="w3-container" id="....kli..">
                       <input  style="display: none; type="text" id="numerochipescondido" name="numerochipescondido" value="<?php echo $row['numerochip']; ?>"> 
                       <input  style="display: none; type="text" id="observacoesescondido" name="observacoesescondido" value="<?php echo $row['observacoes']; ?>"> 
                       <input  style="display: none; type="text" id="idutilizadorescondido" name="idutilizadorescondido" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_utilizador']; ?>"> 
                       <center>
                        <button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['numerochip']; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('id111').style.display='block'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil changeobervations" width:50px height:50px;"></button>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php
                    if($row['velha']){
                     echo 'Velha ';

                   }
                   if($row['prenha']){

                     echo 'Prenha ';

                   }
                   if($row['refugo']){

                    echo 'Refugo ';

                  }
                  if($row['grupo4']){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

                       echo $row['titulogrupo'];
                    }

                  }
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Data1']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Data2']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Data3']; ?> </td>

              </tr>

              <?php } ?>


            </table>

            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"name="submit_x" value="Submeter Lista de Animais a Encontrar(Individual)"> <br> <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"name="submit_y" value="Eliminar Animais Selecionados(Individual)"> <br> <br>
            <form action="deletedb.php" method="post">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"name="submit_d" value="Apagar a minha lista total">
            </form>
          </form>
          <br>


        </br>
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width:300px">

         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Os meus Chips a encontrar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
          ?>
          <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row['ovelhas'];?></td> 
         </tr>

         <?php } ?>
         <!-- Começa aqui o apagar -->
         <form action="apagarOvelhasEncontrar2.php" method="post">
           <br>
           <tr>     
             <td> 
              <button type="submit" name="submit_x" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar Ovelhas a Encontrar</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </form>


      </table>
    </br>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please add the real code where you're assigning $result3. Also, try running your query in MySQL to make sure it's supposed to return more than 1 row.

Comment: Which `</div>` you closed in `<td>` of `<?php echo $row['row5'];?`

Comment: @alpadev i put the real code

Comment: @apladev i did the query and return the group I want. The problem is that it does not put the result in several rows

Comment: don't write mysqli_connect into mysqli_query

Comment: Use a different variable name when iterating on $result3, ATM it's overriding you're $result row.

Comment: `$result3 = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(", "u518178166_serra"), $sql3);` that doesn't work that way and you should have gotten an error about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable when fetching $result3 etc.

```
if($row['grupo4']){
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

                   echo $row3['titulogrupo'];
                }
```